# Unwanted space on both side of multiline inline element

Tags: html, css

I have an horizontal menu with buttons that can have one or two lines of text. With single line buttons the width of the button equal the width of text. But with multiple line buttons, extra white space is added on both side of the text.

See exemple :

[image: menu white space issue]

HTML (tried with no line break and no white space between tags, didn't help) :

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    max-width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 0;
}
li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}
li a span {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Fiddle illustrating the issue : http://jsfiddle.net/gxy9fa9w/

Of course this is a well known issue, but every fixes I tried didn't help : making the span floating left, put `font-size: 0` on the parent and `font-size: 16px` on the child, negative box-shadow, various display type on a, span and li... The problem seems to be related with the a element : without, I can fix the issue by just making the span floating left, but with it I just can't remove this unwanted spaces.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the “well known issue” (supposing you mean the issue with white space between inline element tags), but is a complete different matter altogether: You constricted your `li` elements to a `max-width` of `100px`, and that is the width your `li` element takes here, because the text content you want to put into it is wider than a 100 pixels. Of course the text breaks, but that does not magically make the `li` width “shrink back” to a lower value …

Comment: Side note, you can remove the display:block on the li since you floated it left.

Comment: CBroe's comment is correct. If you add a line break (`<br>` tag) it will do what you wish, since it isn't trying to stretch beyond your max-width anymore.

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/gxy9fa9w/3/

Comment: Interesting, but I can't control the text within the buttons and manually put line breaks. Beside that, the menu is supposed to be responsive, so the max-width of li can change and so the line breaks.

Comment: Fixed that with dirty js.

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute to span:

```
span{
  display:block;
}
```

Because span is **inline**, it doesn't fill its parent

Comment: This make the span fill its parent, but the extra space are now in the span, and not out of it.

Comment: That's because your li which is the ground father of span have max-width=100px so, the span will broke in two line and some space in the middle span will be appeared